# Can someone merge my accounts

Tags: support, merge-accounts

I submitted a request for merging two accounts of mine yesterday:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/45811/daniel `merge delete`

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/35878/daniel-conde `merge keep`

The first one has a myopenid login credential, the second has a gmail login credential.

Is this delay normal, and I should wait more, or maybe, how can I know if there is a problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Delay is very normal, as the team probably gets thousands of emails a day, so it takes time to get to yours.

Comment: You'll have to be patient; you did what you can and now have to wait for a human to handle the request.